# Adding Dynamic content using JSF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

hi chums I am new to JSF and I got stuck in JSF problem.I want to add dynamically my content in my JSF page.My requirment is that I have one facelets which I have to add in my page after some event.

### My page  contains

two fields 'user name' and 'answer' 
and 
two buttons 'login' and 'recover password'

### Facelet contains

a field and just a button

Now I want that when I run my this page it should show only Page contents(described above)
and if user press the button `'recover password'` then it should show the facelet under the components of page on the same page mean after pressing the button , page could include facelet.
But now when I run my code it show both as I haven't put any logic to add 2nd facelet dynamically.
Here a patch of my code given below

```
 <h:inputText id="txtLogin" styleClass="textEntry" required="true" requiredMessage="Username is required."> 
                    </h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="answer" styleClass="textEntry" autocomplete="off" required="true" requiredMessage="Answer is required."></h:inputText>
                                    <h:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" styleClass="formbutton" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
                    <h:commandButton id="btnRecover" value="Recover" styleClass="formbutton" onclick="btnRecover_Click"/>
```

Now I want when this `btnRecover_click` click then it include this facelet or run this code

```
<div class="divPadding">
            <ui:include id="passrecov" src="ucPasswordRecovery.xhtml" rendered="false"/>
        </div>
```

Keep in mind that I have to do this with JSF and don't want to do this with JavaScript

Thanks

Comment: You can use the "rendered" attribute to get the desired behavior, no need of javascript as suggested in the answer. To make it work, you should wrap the <ui:include> inside an ui container component like <h:panelGrid>, change the rendered value in server and rerender this container, then your ui will be displayed

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but how? can you give me a small example?

Comment: should I do this 
"
<h:panelGrid rendered="false">
<div class="divPadding">
            <ui:include id="passrecov" src="ucPasswordRecovery.xhtml" rendered="false"/>
        </div>
<h:panelGrid>
"
But it still didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post a sample using  with 1 column, remember that you could use another ui container.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="login">
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:inputText id="txtLogin" styleClass="textEntry" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Username is required."> 
            </h:inputText>
            <h:inputText id="answer" styleClass="textEntry" autocomplete="off"
                required="true" requiredMessage="Answer is required.">
            </h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" styleClass="formbutton"
                onclick="btnSave_Click" />
            <h:commandButton id="btnRecover" value="Recover" styleClass="formbutton"
                action="#{loginBean.showPassRecovery}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid id="passRecovery">
        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{not loginBean.loginEnabled}">
        <ui:include id="passrecov" src="ucPasswordRecovery.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And your managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean {
    private boolean loginEnabled;

    public LoginBean() {
        loginEnabled = true;
    }

    //getters and setters...

    //this method will return void, so the page will be refreshed with the new
    //loginEnabled value. this time the components inside "login" panelGrid won't be rendered
    //but "passRecovery" panelGrid components will.
    public void showPassRecovery() {
        loginEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am still getting the issues.first of all in "<h:panelGrid id="passRecovery">" this panel grid "<ui:include id="passrecov" src="ucPasswordRecovery.xhtml" rendered="#{not loginBean.loginEnabled}" is not working but when i put rendered="#{not loginBean.loginEnabled} attribute in "<h:panelGrid id="passRecovery" rendered="#{not loginBean.loginEnabled}>" then it start works.Now after this my issue is that when facelet added in that page then it removes the previous contents of panelgrid(ref: h:panelGrid rendered="#{loginBean.loginEnabled}">).I want that panelgrid still remain present- please help

Comment: Please let me know If anything is unclear- I will post it again as an issue and will send you the link of that one

Comment: @SSK answer edited, I've added another `<h:panelGrid>` that will handle the `rendered` tag attribute.

Comment: I run this code exactly but now it is only showing facelet.It means this grid is rendering only
 "<h:panelGrid id="passRecovery">
        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{not loginBean.loginEnabled}">
        <ui:include id="passrecov" src="ucPasswordRecovery.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>" I am sick from its this behaviour

Comment: @SSK yes I've tested the code and it renders the include with no problem. What's your exact problem?

Comment: thx for reply - I told you in above comment that by running your code it only render facelet and doesn't show the real contents that I want to print first(before facelet)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14934/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-ssk)